# how can I easily add new information in existing node (firebase + Swift 3)

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a new programmer and struggling with firebase...the content on firebase's website is not enough for people that don't have experience.. I'm trying to add new information in existing node(-KrgRoE_GoZGoMZk_bxl) but I simply can't do it... see that I can get my last register using this code below:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let last = ref?.child("CAD").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)

        last!.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
           print(snapshot.children.allObjects.last)
```

See the firebase data:

```
tIFgcSHDWAYguUJ5jNPYhfuqT903
   KrgRoE_GoZGoMZk_bxl
{
  "COORDENADAS" : "(-25.462915289401252, -49.290945083371739)",
  "DATA" : "16/08/2017",
  "HORA" : "16:9:23",
  "LOCALIZACAO" : "Rua Professor Basílio Ovídio da Costa, 19",
  "PERIODO" : "1 Hora",
  "VALOR" : 3
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write), you use `setValue` to add new data, and  `updateChildValues` to change data. Also, instead of observing the value of all data under the current user, you can use a query to limit the number of children returned to the very last one. Now I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to add to the child node, but accessing one child and adding new data to it could look something like this:

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() 
let last = ref?.child("CAD").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)

last!.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
   print(snapshot.value)
   let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
   // Do whatever you need to do with value

   let key = snapshot.key

   last.child(key).setValue(["newData": newData]) // add new key/value pair
})
```

Comment: Jean, I had to use answer to add my comments about your answer because It was too much characters... hope you can help. Thanks